# What does ALT+F+C+N do, and how to undo it?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I was trying to figure out how to copy/paste a forumla without changing the references, and I found on a forum board post that someone said "Copy the cell, then do ALT+F+C+N".

I tried this without giving it much thought, and it wiped out my whole spreadsheet.  I closed and reopened it, and it is at some really old saved state.

I looked further down on this forum post, and people seemed to be laughing about this ALT+F+C+N thing like it was a joke.  It seems some jackass decided to post it like it's seriously the answer, but really it does something completely different.

What does ALT+F+C+N do in Excel, and how can I undo it?

Comment: I think that shortcut is File -> Close -> No to the save prompt.  I think I'm screwed...  What kind of jerk posts something like that on a forum board.

Comment: Sometimes.. people on the internet need to get a life. Its the same kind of people who tell people to rm -rf their computers.

Comment: I guess some people like to make others feel stupid, which I definitely do feel stupid now.  Oh well, I won't be doing that again.

Comment: +1 for bringing attention that internet isn't exactly a trustworthy place.  Remember the rule of 3: if there's 3 distinct sources that that agree on same matter, there's high probability that it's true.   That's kinda the beauty of the stackexchange; if you see an answer with 3 three upvotes, that's 3 other people that either agree or like the answer.  They do good troll control too...

Comment: Ctrl+S is your friend.

Comment: @Jim - Don't feel too bad; there was a tool on Server Fault a few weeks ago who tricked people into wiping their servers by using a cleverly designed line of code. Some people are just trolls, and at least you didn't wipe your company server.

Comment: In general, the rule of thumb is, if you don't know what a piece of code does and trust the source you got it from, don't run it on your machine. If you have a vm just for testing that's easy to restore, then you can try things in it that are a bit more risky, but even then, there might be code nasty enough to to get out through some exploit to damage the rest of your system. On Linux, there are these very short strings of less than 20 characters you can type at a command line that look just like gibberish that will crash most systems they are run on (fork bombs). You have to be careful!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In Excel, when you hold ALT it will show the shortcut hotkeys. If you follow the trail it looks like ALT+F+C+N goes as follows:

```
ALT > F selects 'File' > C select 'Close' > N selects 'No' at the save prompt
```

So its a shortcut to close out of Excel without saving, so whatever you didn't have saved at the time is unlikely to be recovered :( Sorry man, there are tons of jerks on the internet

There is however, an AutoRecover feature in Excel 2010, if enabled I believe the default location is something like `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\`

There could be incremental backups in there, depending on your settings / version!

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Unfortunately, I'm using Excel 2007, and even though I have autorecover turned on, it didn't have anything.  Oh well, it took maybe an hour to redo the work I lost.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry that happened to you.  Sometimes the internet can be a jerk.

Just an idea about your original Excel problem, if you still haven't gotten it figured.  If you change the references in your original formula to absolute references from relative references then copy it, that should do the trick.

If you don't know what absolute and relative references are, just put dollar signs (`$`) in front of your cell address and it will not change when you copy the formula.  For example, if you have a formula like `=A1`  and then copy it two cells to the right (into cell C1) it will change to `=C1`.  If you enter it as `=$A$1`  then copy that cell anywhere in the sheet, it will remain `=$A$1`.

If you need further information look for some Excel tutorials on the web.  I recommend [chandoo.org](http://chandoo.org/).  The guy that runs the site is really well informed and a good teacher.  I send my colleagues there all the time.

Comment: Thank you much for the answer; that does answer the original question which caused me to look at that other forum where I ended up getting the bad answer.  +1